# Change HTML5 video tag width and height through Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video

I have the following code in client side JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("#player1").html(
    '<video width=' + width + ' height=' + height + ' autoplay>' +
      '<source src=' + curPlayListHrefs[0] + ' type="video/youtube"></source>' +
    '</video>'
  );
});
```

I tried:

```
  var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
  video.videoHeight = 300;
  video.videoWidth = 700;
```

Is it possible for me to change the width/height of the video tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting its width and height attributes

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
video.setAttribute('height', '300');
video.setAttribute('width', '700');
```

or setting its width and height properties

```
var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
video.height = 300;
video.width = 700;
```

Comment: thanks for quick response. Option 2 works. However if put the same code in $(window).resize(). it does not reset video height and width. To resize window, I expand/collapse browser window. Would u know the reason? TIA

Comment: I found that if the code is executed after the execution of $('video').mediaelementplayer({...});, then it does not reset the video tag. would u know the reason?

Comment: In option 1, you have to use  '300px' and '700px'.